Why does DeviceCapabilities return incorrect paper dimensions for B4 (JIS) in a Unidrv UI Plug-In, and how can I adjust it?
I am working with a Unidrv UI Plug-In in a Windows printer driver and using the GetDvCp2 software to obtain paper sizes. For B4 (JIS), I see a discrepancy: DC_PAPERS[11] returns "B4 (JIS) 250 x 354 mm", but DC_PAPERSIZE[11] gives dimensions as 2570 x 3641.

I would like to know:
1、Why this mismatch occurs in DeviceCapabilities.
2、From which resource or configuration file these sizes are retrieved.
3、How I might modify the DeviceCapabilities function in my Unidrv UI Plug-In to ensure it returns the correct paper dimensions.
